# MVC - returning data via ajax call renders it as page

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

New to MVC.

Scenario is. Using a 3rd party upload library for images. When a form is submitted, I want to make a call via ajax to submit the data and return the inserted item id. I then use that id for the 3rd party upload library to build folders where the images will be uploaded to.

I have the ajax call working and inserting the data to the database and getting the inserted id. But when the debug returns from the controller, it renders the id as a whole page.

Missing something fundamental here to MVC I think.

cshtml file:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
              <input type="submit" value="Add Item" id="submitItem" />
              <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                  $("#submitItem").submit(function () {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    insertData();
                  });
                });

                function insertData()
                {
                  var requestData = {
                    userID: $("#hdnUserID").val(),
                    title: $("#title").val(),
                    typeID: $("#typeID").val(),
                    description: $("#description").val()
                  };

                  $.ajax({
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("ItemUserDashBoard", "Home") %>',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                      // your data could be a View or Json or what ever you returned in your action method 
                      // parse your data here
                      alert(data);
                      $("#fine-uploader-gallery").fineUploader("uploadStoredFiles");
                    },
                    processData: false
                  });
                }
              </script>
            </div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ItemUserDashBoard(ItemAppraise.Models.iaDashBoardModel objItemUserDashBoard)
    {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        using (dbContext)
        {
          ia_items iaItem = new ia_items
          {
            userID = objItemUserDashBoard.iaItems.userID,
            typeID = objItemUserDashBoard.iaItems.typeID,
            title = objItemUserDashBoard.iaItems.title,
            description = objItemUserDashBoard.iaItems.description,
            lastUpdate = DateTime.Now
          };

          dbContext.ia_items.Add(iaItem);
          dbContext.SaveChanges();

          //objItemUserDashBoard.iaItems.itemID = iaItem.itemID;
          return Json(iaItem.itemID.ToString());
        }
      }
      else{
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Fiddler shows it as having a header of Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8.

But the page renders under the control url 'http://localhost:55689/Home/ItemUserDashBoard' with just the item id showing.

How do I get the data back just to use in the success part of the ajax call and not be rendered? Is this Partial Views or something similar?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard MVC. Any call made to a controller is handled just like a web request. So if i understand you correctly - the result of your httpPost is being rendered instead of the desired View? This is because you are returning JSON, so the controller assumes that is what you are trying to render. If you want a View to be rendered instead (and somehow use that response data) you could try setting the return type to `ActionResult` and returning a `View("nameofview");` You can pass your response data to that view in a [number of ways](https://chsakell.com/2013/05/02/4-basic-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc/).

*As a side note* I think the problem you are facing could be better solved with [Web Api](https://www.asp.net/web-api) instead of MVC. It works well with MVC and could be a simpler way of implementing your desired functionality. Separating your post requests and database interactions from the logic which decides which View to return.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael.
Yes, the return is being rendered instead of returning the the View I was on.
I basically want to just get the data and use that in the success part of the ajax call. The information is invisible to the actual View. I just need to pass it onto the 3rd party image uploader so I can build a folder based on that number.

Comment: Good point about the Web Api. This ajax call I'm making has nothing to do with the View as such. It is just a means to insert the data and get the returned id. Like I said, the "Add Item View" should know nothing about this happening and the end result is the item (data and images) are added and the page moves on to the "List Items View" with the newly added item displayed.

Comment: No problem, i hope it helped. 

When i was initially learning MVC and ASP.Net - i found things all became much clearer and simpler with Web API. Typically any MVC controllers i have are pretty simple - all the database stuff happens in Web API. Leading to a better separation of concerns.

Even if you `return View("relaventView")` and pass some data down with it as a result of your httpPost as i suggested - i think it will cause a re-render which isn't ideal. So if you have the time WebApi and Ajax on the front end can work together transparent to your user - no re-rendering.

Comment: Makes sense. I've been a C# ,net developer for years and have finally decided to change over to using MVC. I think I'm trying to be too much of a purist in doing this making sure EVERYTHING is MVC based. And your point is well made..........that the sum of the solution can consist of many parts. Thanks again for re-grounding me in the way of the "net".